# Converting rows with too many values to columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Lets say I have a dataset like this.

```
ID  Item
1   A
2   B
3   A
1   C
2   B
2   B
1   A
3   B
```

The actual dataset has 50K rows and 8.5K distinct Item values.

Now I want to transpose the rows to columns for each Id such that we are counting the values for each item for each user. Like below

```
ID  A   B   C
1   2   0   1
2   0   3   0
3   1   1   0
```

Now if I have like set no. of Item values then I can hardcode them in case aggregate statement.

Something like

```
select ID, count(case when Item ='A' then 1 else Null end) A, 
count(case when Item='B' then 1 else Null end) B... and so on.
```

But in this case I have 8.5K unique Item. This would be too much task to do as above in sql.

How can I achieve this is Sql and ii) Python. Remember I have 50K rows and 8.5k unique items, so python looping might get a bit slow.

But my first aim is to do this in sql, since this is a sample data of 50K. when data grows bigger sql would still hold it well, but python there would become slow I feel.In python I can try some code too.But again when data is more than 50K obs then python would get it slow too

Please advise

Not using Postgresql and using HANA, so function specific to Postgres might not work. Please suggest generic sql way.

Comment: What you are looking for is a "Cross Tab" query, which MySQL does not support. It has to be code (or a stored procedure), or a query similar to the one you proposed. But that query should use `SUM` or the ELSE in the COUNT should be `ELSE NULL`; COUNT counts 0's.

Comment: True. But i can't use the one I proposed. I have 8.5K unique values in Item. Cant hardcode 8.5K times. Its 8k line code then. I am using HANA and not Mysql. and i am looking for a generic sql query outside of any specific function like Pivot or Crosstab since PIVOT and CROSSTAB won't be there in HANA

Comment: Do you need to display that information somewhere (export) in that particular form or you need to have access to counts in your app to calculate something?

Comment: Basically I am working on a dataset which is shown as 1 above. I need to transform it to 2 so that I can use 2 to work on some further analysis I am doing. It is imperative that data needs to be in 2 format for the analysis to be possible. So that is why I need to create a new dataset to convert from 1 to 2.

Comment: Why not just [`SELECT ID, Item, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY ID, Item`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfea0/6)?

Comment: How would that convert rows to columns? It would just group it by each user and item but not convert the values of Item to columns

Comment: Is switching from 1 to 2 a one time event?  If so performance isn't a huge issue.

Comment: @Baktaawar what I mean is why do you actually want a 8.5k column table? Just index on `ID, Item` and you can do any analysis efficiently. Also @mention me if you want me to see your replies.

Comment: @EoinS Yes it;s a one time event. I NEED this in 8.5K columns. I am using that in a matrix factorization algorithm which would work on 8.5 column matrix and factories it into two matrices. So my data needs to be in that format

Comment: If this is truly a one time event I woudl go with @Mr.F 's solution.  But you mention the values become bigger?  If it's a once off transformation then python is the way to go (read: the only way to go).  Performance shouldn't be an issue, even it it takes a few hours.  If in fact the table will be growing then you could perform the transformation on only new data.

Comment: How well does matrix factorization work in (1) SQL and (2) a matrix with thousands of rows and columns?

Comment: @EoinS and Alex: I am building a prototype matrix factorization algorithm. I am going to code the matrix factorization(MF) algorithm in Python as it is very difficult to do that in Sql. My dataset is in HANA and WOULD be in HANA. For MF, i need the dataset in format (2). Its imperative. My aim is to do the data manipulation in Sql itself. It's a one time effort for one type of dataset. But the dataset would change. The operation would remain same, but dataset would change depending upon which company's data we are working on. Idea is to have an app running the result of MF, with data on HANA

Comment: @Baktaawar if you're not using MySQL, you should probably remove it from the question's tags; and there is no generic (SQL) query outside of pivots and crosstabs (when supported). "Generic" sql queries do not allow the columns present to vary based on data. If MySQL is involved, I can show a technique to use a query to create the ~8.5k column query.

Comment: What is that query?

Comment: @Baktaawar see answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to do this in python, you should look at the `pandas` library

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
    'Item': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B' , 'A', 'B']
})

pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Item'])
```

Output:

```
Item A  B   C
ID          
1   2   0   1
2   0   3   0
3   1   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks. But my concern is it might become slow when rows and values become bigger than 50K and 8.5K. So sql would be better there. Any idea on how to do in sql?

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. However I am now trying to prototype it in Python. For that I am pulling the data from HANA to python. I used the following code. It is giving me some NULL values when pulled. The original table in HANA doesn't have any NULL. Not sure why is that? 

sql=""" 


select * from 
"Table A"

"""


df=psql.read_sql(sql,conn)

Comment: I'm not familiar with HANA, I'm afraid. What are you using to connect? What do you get if you do something like ``cur = conn.cursor(); cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "Table A"'); cur.fetchmany(5)``

Answer (score 0):

For a SQL solution, how about using your SQL technique but scripting it?  Not sure how it would hold up but you can give it a shot if you haven't already tried.
Run something like this to generate script of all the columns you need:

```
select distinct 'sum(case when ITEM = ''' + ITEM + ''' then 1 else 0 end) ' + ITEM + ',' from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Then copy and paste the results to come up with:

```
select 
  ID,
  **<COPY AND PASTE RESULTS HERE>**
from TEST_DATA
group by ID;
```

Comment: I am not sure that command would work. You are putting sum statement within quotes. I removed the quotes and tried too. Error. 

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near " + ITEM + ": line 1 col 74 (at pos 74)

Comment: Try this:  `select distinct concat('sum(case when ITEM = ''', ITEM, ''' then 1 else 0 end) ', ITEM, ',') from YOUR_TABLE;`

Comment: Remember that this is generating the script for you to use, not actually executing it.  That is why the sum statement is within quotes.  You'll have to manually copy and paste the results into the second statement (also removing the last comma).  This is just so you don't have to type out cases for 8.5k different items.

Comment: Didn't work. 

SAP DBTech JDBC: [316]: wrong number of arguments in function invocation: line 1 col 17 (at pos 16)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  See the demo here:  http://rextester.com/WVGGSY40997

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. However I am now trying to prototype it in Python. For that I am pulling the data from HANA to python. I used the following code. It is giving me some NULL values when pulled. The original table in HANA doesn't have any NULL. Not sure why is that? 

sql=""" 


select * from 
"Table A"

"""


df=psql.read_sql(sql,conn)

Answer (score 0):

This query can generate the query you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT ID"
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT(", COUNT(CASE Item WHEN '", Item, "' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `", Item, "`")
        ORDER BY Item
        )
    , "FROM `theTable` "
    , "GROUP BY ID"
  ) AS theQuery
FROM `theTable`
;
```

....but I only know `GROUP_CONCAT` exists for sure in MySQL and does not in MSSQL; I don't know about other database systems. Also, in MySQL, you will need to increase the maximum length allowed by the function by preceding this query with a statement like

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

...or changing server config to make the default max larger.
...where "1000000" is a length big enough to not truncate the resulting string.

If the query is so big that group_concat cannot fit it no matter what setting: you could run multiple of these queries, using WHEREs to reduce the `Item` values processed, to generate smaller ", COUNT(...), COUNT(" lists; and then manually merge those results.

Of course, even if this generates the query want, I am not positive MySQL will even accept a query that long.