# Mysql Pivot table dynamic number of columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a dynamic attributes table in mysql

```
attributes
----------
attribute_id    description
1               Code produit
2               Code millesime  
3               Titre du produit
...             ....
```

And a products table:

```
products
--------
product_id  attribute_id    value
1020        1               xyz
1020        2               zyt
1020        3               UUU
....        ...             ....
```

I need an sql statement to pivot the products table so that I get the following:

```
products_pivot
--------------

product_id  Code produit    Code millesime  Titre du produit    ...
1020        xyz             zyt             UUU                 ...
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this in mysql, given that the number of columns generated would be dynamic?

And if so, I was also wondering what the performance would be for let's say 1000 products, each product containing about 100 attributes. (That means 100000 records in the products table...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting rows with too many values to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424842/converting-rows-with-too-many-values-to-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Q: *Is there a simple way* A: No, there is no simple way to achieve that